# Show/hide div - DRY

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have 3 views, `SectionAView`, `SectionBView` and `SectionCView`.
Each view has 2 radio buttons, `Yes` and `No`.

When I select `Yes` in `SectionAView`, it should display `SectionBView`. Selecting ‘No’ should display `SectionCView` (and hide `SectionBView`)

The application could have many views, so I guess my question is to keep things a little bit more DRY and possibly the best way to approach this?

I have something like this:

```
var Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        block: null
    }
});

var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Section
});

var SectionAView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',

    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new Section();
        this.collection = new List();
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        this.render();
    },
    events: {
         'click .section-a': 'updateElement'
    },
    render: function(e) {
         this.$el.find('.section-b').hide();
         return this;
    },
    updateElement: function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var activeValue = $target.val();
        // Default - SectionA is displayed (at all times)
       this.model.set('block', 'section-a');
       this.collection.push(this.model);
       if (activeValue == 'no') {
           this.$el.find('.section-b').show();
           this.$el.find('.section-c').hide();
       } else {
           this.$el.find('.section-c').show();
           this.$el.find('.section-b').hide();
       }
     }
   });

   var SectionBView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        model: Section,

        initialize: function() {
             this.render();
        },
        render: function(e) {
            this.$el.find('.section-b').hide();
            return this;
        },
      });

      var SectionCView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: 'body',
            initialize: function() {
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(e) {
                this.$el.find('.section-c').hide();
                return this;
            }

        });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="section-a" data-active-value="true">
        <h2>Section A</h2>
        <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="section-a" class="section-a" value="yes" /></label>
        <label>No<input type="radio" name="section-a" class="section-a" value="no" /></label>
    </div>

    <div class="section-b" data-active-value="">
        <h2>Section B</h2>
        <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="section-b" class="section-b" value="yes" /></label>
        <label>No<input type="radio" name="section-b" class="section-b" value="no" /></label>
    </div>

    <div class="section-c">
        <h2>Section C</h2>
        <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="section-c" class="section" value="yes" /></label>
        <label>No<input type="radio" name="section-c" class="section" value="no" /></label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I believe you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @gdoron I have updated my question with some code. You can see, the more `Sections` I'm adding more `Views`. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better if you cache elements and use toggleClass:

```
render: function(e) {
    //cache        
    var elemB = this.$el.find('.section-b')
    var elemC = this.$el.find('.section-c')
    elemB.toggleClass('show', false);//remove 'show' class if any
         return this;
    },
updateElement: function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var activeValue = $target.val();
    // Default - SectionA is displayed (at all times)
    this.model.set('block', 'section-a');
    this.collection.push(this.model);
    elemB.toggleClass('show', (activeValue === 'no'));
    elemC.toggleClass('show', (activeValue === 'yes'))
    }
```

Additionally if you set activeValue to true or false, you will not have to check for 'no' value and code becomes shorter

```
elemB.toggleClass('show', activeValue);
```

Comment: An old answer, but worth stating. `(activeValue === 'no')` already returns a boolean value, so using it in a ternary operator to then return a boolean is redundant.